# How to get formatted text with PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

In excel I have cells that contains formatted text (bold, color, italic). How can I get these values exactly as they are in excel with PHPExcel?

I tried with: getFormattedValue() but it just returns the normal value, without formatting.

The desired output should be in html format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're talking about Rich Text Objects, then bold/colour/italic etc aren't a property of the cell content, but of the cell itself.... the only style feature that is applied when calling `getFormattedValue()` is the number format mask for the cell (that actually changes the cell content itself).... ie the style feature that would change a numeric value like `12345.678` to a string like `$ 12,345.68`, or `42310` to a string like `02-Nov-2015`.

It's not certain quite what you'd expect `getFormattedValue()` to return in terms of other formatting styles such as bold/colour/italic.... text strings don't have any inherent concept of bold, or red, or underlined, they're just text.

If you want html markup, there is no native PHP function that will do this, though you can take a look at how the HTML Writer renders style (clue: styles are set for a `<td>` cell, not for the text content inside that cell). So if you want html markup with style settings, then you'd need to read the cell style and write a little helper function to generate the markup from that.

Comment: hey, what exactly you end up doing? Could you share snippet here